# yaml dependency in R won't update in Windows

Tags: r, yaml, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I'm on a windows machine and I'm trying  to knit an RMarkdown  document with RStudio. When I press the 'knit' button in  RStudio,  I  get a "requires an updated version of the yaml package" message. I `install.packages("yaml")` to find a message saying  something along the  lines of "binary source needs_compilation." I check the  CRAN page  for `yaml` and it seems that the Microsoft binaries are not up to date  with the the more recent Mac version (2.1.14 < 2.1.15). I think this is the reason why I can't knit an RMarkdown document, but I do not  know how to work around this.

This  error popped  up a few days ago and I'm not really sure  how to fix it.  I've been  knitting documents pretty  consistently until  now and don't really know what to do.

Any help or guidance would be  greatly appreciated.

[image: screenshot of me struggling with yaml]

[image: screenshot of me struggling with versions]

Comment: http://kbroman.org/pkg_primer/pages/build.html

Comment: The `yaml` package was updated 2 days ago, and a binary package isn't available for it on CRAN yet.  You could build your own following the instructions in Cedric's link, or wait, or (maybe) install an older version of RStudio.

Answer (score 0):

@cedric's [link](http://kbroman.org/pkg_primer/pages/build.html) helped out. I had to `install()` the `yaml` package using `devtools`